# How to check that an internet connection is available from a Windows local service?

Tags: windows, service

How to check that an internet connection is available from a Windows local service? the InternetGetConnectedState API can not be used from a service according MSDN.

Comment: why can't you try to run 'ping' command

Answer (score 2):

Which OS ?

Windows 8 :

```
GetInternetConnectionProfile()
```

[more informations on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-FR/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.connectivity.networkinformation.getinternetconnectionprofile)

Windows 7 :

```
System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable();
```

[more informations on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.getisnetworkavailable.aspx)

For all : 
Why you don't use `ping` ?

**Edit : I had not seen the comment about ping**

Comment: ping is not enough. Sometimes you can ping but can not access the website